# After MAMP upgrade, phpMyAdmin link on start page greyed

Tags: installation, mamp

So after I downloaded the upgrade to MAMP and installed it, the link on the start page for phpMyAdmin is greyed out. MAMP had saved the original installation in a new folder. Noticed that Sequel Pro.app was in the old folder but not the new install  folder. Could this be the issue? Can I just move the Sequel Pro app to the new MAMP folder?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, had to downgrade PHP from 7.1 to 7.0

Weird